# Inflar Layout em uma Service

Tags: android, android-layout, floating

No casso esse código faz uma janela flutuante com um botão para encerrar a atividade, então como faço agora para inflar nela um layout, ou outra forma de construir um layout dentro da service.

```
public class FloatingWindow extends Service {

    WindowManager wm;
    LinearLayout ll;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate();

        wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

        ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        ll.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParameteres = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 400);
        ll.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(235,164,164,164));
        ll.setLayoutParams(layoutParameteres);

        final WindowManager.LayoutParams parameters = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                700, 600, WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        parameters.gravity = Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.CENTER;
        parameters.x = 0;
        parameters.y = 0;

      Button     stop = new Button(this);
    stop.setText("Stop");
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams btnParameters = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        stop.setLayoutParams(btnParameters);

        ll.addView(stop);
        wm.addView(ll, parameters);

        ll.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            WindowManager.LayoutParams updatedParameters = parameters;
            double x;
            double y;
            double pressedX;
            double pressedY;

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                        x = updatedParameters.x;
                        y = updatedParameters.y;

                        pressedX = event.getRawX();
                        pressedY = event.getRawY();

                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        updatedParameters.x = (int) (x + (event.getRawX() - pressedX));
                        updatedParameters.y = (int) (y + (event.getRawY() - pressedY));

                        wm.updateViewLayout(ll, updatedParameters);

                    default:
                        break;
                }

                return false;
            }
        });

        stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                wm.removeView(ll);
                stopSelf();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        stopSelf();
    }
```

Comment: Tente explicar melhor o que pretende. Uma das principais características de um serviço é não ter *layout* (interacção com o usuário)

Comment: Então oque eu quero é uma janela flutuante, ok, com esse código já tenho, mais como é uma service não tem layout, e eu não consigo e nem sei como faço para obter esse resultado.

Answer (score 2):

Amigo você pode fazer desse jeito para construir uma view no seu service.

```
mWindowManager = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    mLogoHead = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recording_view, null);
    WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

    layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
    layoutParams.x = 100;
    layoutParams.y = 100;
    mWindowManager.addView(mLogoHead, mLayoutParams = layoutParams);
    mLogoHead.setOnTouchListener(this);
    mLogoHead.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: o (mLogoHead) é oque?

Comment: é a view que eu coloquei para construir pode se chamar como você quiser.